# How do I lay out numbered business cards so I can easily print and hand-cut them?

Tags: print-design

I have some business cards(made in indesign) with different numbers/pages, from 1 to 400 ,on them...I would like to know, if there is a way to arrange somehow the pages, so when i print them, they can come arranged and ready for cut, without me arranging them afterall.
they have to come 3 x 6 cards(18) on an A3 ark. so it mean that the first card on 1 Ark(A3) has number 1, and the first card on the next ark 2(A3), has number 2 and so on......

ps. It is difficult to explain it, so I hope you understand:-)
Thank you
Regards Dina

Comment: There are specialized programs for that kind of job. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a commercial printer they will be able to Impose or print multiples on a page, in this case 'cut and stack' [see Imposition Types](http://www.montax-imposer.com/) You will then have to ask the printer to be careful so that the order is not compromised. To do this your self manually would entail some tricky maths and rearranging of your pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Trivial to generate the text in a spreadsheet and auto-flow that into an arranged template which will appropriately position the numbers using InDesign or any decent page layout or drawing program (put copies of the business cards on the master page).

Comment: Or even write a macro in MS Publisher, which I've done for books of raffle tickets. (I like VBA and Publisher was available and easy for a low-end job: don't shoot me!)